# Where should i get kibana credentials after I create aws elastic search domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kibana, amazon-ses, aws-elasticsearch, aws-access-policy

I have setup a configuration to store emails sent via SES. I followed below link

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ses-email-sending-history/

problem I am facing is that when i open elastic search domain which is configured to store SES sent emails it is asking for kibana credentials. I looked all over but I couldn't find it anywhere else. It's not even mentioned anything about kibana credentials in above url.

I am using AWS free tier account.

Comment: That depends on what kind of security policy you applied the elastic search cluster.

Comment: As mentioned in this [URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-create-domain.html)

1) For network configuration I have gave pubic access
2) For access policy I choose Allow open access to the domain.

Comment: Not network configuration, the [access policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-ac.html)

Comment: For access policy I choose Allow open access to the domain

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html